# Count how many times an element is repeated or not repeated in a sequence (R)

Tags: r, sequence

I have a sequence of events, coded as A,B, and C. For each element I need to count how many times this element was repeated before but if it is not repeated, the counter should decrease by one for each row. On the first encounter of each item the counter for it is zero. For example:

```
x<-c('A','A','A','B','C','C','A','B','A','C')
y<-c(0,1,2,0,0,1,-2,-4,-4,-3)
cbind(x,y)

      x   y   
 [1,] "A" "0" 
 [2,] "A" "1" 
 [3,] "A" "2" 
 [4,] "B" "0" 
 [5,] "C" "0" 
 [6,] "C" "1" 
 [7,] "A" "-2"
 [8,] "B" "-4"
 [9,] "A" "-4"
[10,] "C" "-3"
```

I need to generate column y from x. I know that I can use `rle` for run length, but I don't know how to get time since the last encounter of specific event to make counter decrease.

Comment: Sorry, small mistake, on row 7 the value should be -2. On row 7 event == 'A', the previous value for 'A' counter was 2 (row 3), so on row 4 counter = 1, on row 5 counter = 0, on row 6 counter = -1, on row 7  counter =-2. The same goes for B - the last counter value for B was 0 and there were 4 rows since the previous B.The counter increases by one if the current event is the same as on previous row, and decreases by one if it is not, and there are separate counters for each event type.

Comment: Fixed also the A value on row 9, mistake there as well. That what happens when I count things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is sort of an `R` way to solve the problem. We can calculate the index of all different elements in `x` the same way, offset it by its initial position and then combine them together.

Calculate the index separately for each unique element in x:

```
library(data.table)
sepIndex <- lapply(unique(x), function(i) { 
    s = cumsum(ifelse(duplicated(rleid(x == i)) & x == i, 1, -1)) + min(which(x == i)); 
    # use `rleid` with `duplicated` to find out the duplicated elements in each block.
    # and assign `1` to each duplicated element and `-1` otherwise and use cumsum for cumulative index
    # offset the index by the initial position of the element `min(which(x == i))`
    replace(s, x != i, NA) 
})
```

Which gives us a list of index for each unique element:

```
sepIndex
# [[1]]
#  [1]  0  1  2 NA NA NA -2 NA -4 NA

# [[2]]
#  [1] NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA -4 NA NA

# [[3]]
#  [1] NA NA NA NA  0  1 NA NA NA -3
```

Combine the list into one using the `Reduce` function should give you what you need:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x), sepIndex)
#  [1]  0  1  2  0  0  1 -2 -4 -4 -3
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way using base R

```
positions <- sapply(unique(x),function(t) which(x %in% t))
values <- sapply(sapply(positions,diff),function(s) c(0,cumsum(ifelse(s>1,-s,s))))
df <- data.frame(positions=unlist(positions),values=unlist(values))
df[with(df,order(positions)),2]
```